# How can I register a RHEL6 server via kickstart without using up a "Management" entitlement?

Tags: linux, redhat, kickstart, rhel6

It seems that the only way I could get RHEL 6 to register is adding the following to the kickstart's `%post` stanza:

```
rhnreg_ks --serverUrl=https://xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com/XMLRPC --sslCACert=/usr/share/rhn/RHNS-CA-CERT --activationkey=<activation key>
```

However, this uses up a "Management" entitlement. How can I accomplish this without using up our valuable "Management" entitlement?

**Side note:** Anyone know of canonical documentation with regards to what these entitlements actually entitle you for?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the differences between Update, Management, Provisioning, and Monitoring Entitlements in RHN?
https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-11277

Looks like you can specific an activation key only for update subscriptions

How do I create an RHN activation key for automated RHN registration of my Red Hat Enterprise Linux systems?
https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-2475

(See the Resolution Step #5 - "Set Add-On Entitlements to "Provisioning" or "Management" depending on the needs of this system")